# Generating self signed certificate using wildcard as CA

Tags: php, docker, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have a following script that generates working server certificate for docker.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -eo pipefail

cd $(dirname $0)

C=PL
ST=Mazovia
L=Warsaw
O="PHP-HTTP"
CN="192.168.56.10"

openssl req -out ca.pem -new -x509 -subj "/C=$C/ST=$ST/L=$L/O=$O/CN=docker-server" -passout pass:password
openssl genrsa -out server.key
openssl req -key server.key -new -out server.req -subj "/C=$C/ST=$ST/L=$L/O=$O/CN=$CN" -passout pass:password
openssl x509 -req -in server.req -CA ca.pem -CAkey privkey.pem -CAserial file.srl -out server.pem -passin pass:password
```

Unfortunately when I replace `CN="192.168.56.10"` with `CN="*"` I'm starting to get an error message:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpClient\Exception\TransportException: SSL: certificate subject name '*' does not match target host name '192.168.56.10' for "https://192.168.56.10:2375/version"
```

For my test script:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Acceptance\Docker;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\CurlHttpClient;

class DockerAcceptanceTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testSomething(): void
    {
        $kernel = self::bootKernel();

        $client = (new CurlHttpClient([
//            'bindto' => '/var/run/docker.sock'
            'local_cert' => __DIR__ . '/../../../ssl-test/client.pem',
            'local_pk' => __DIR__ . '/../../../ssl-test/client.key',
        ]));
        $response = $client->request(
            'GET',
            'https://192.168.56.10:2375/version'
        );

        dump(
//            $client,
            $response->getStatusCode(),
            $response->getContent(),
        );

        $this->assertSame('test', $kernel->getEnvironment());
    }
}
```

How can I generate an SSL Certificate for the server that would ignore Common Name (CN) check ?

Comment: Hopefully no client will accept a wild-card of "*" for the host name check. If you want to disable host name checking you need to do that on the client side. Also, the use of "CN" for host names has been deprecated for 20 years now, host names are supposed to be placed in the Subject Alternative Names extension of the certificate.

Comment: Thank you @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thanks to that comment I was able to find an option in my client ```"verify_host" = false``` which solved the problem. That said I have a feeling it is not a good practice to disable that check in the production. Do you know what are the potential dangers ? Or maybe since the use of CN for hostnames has been deprecated for so long the host verification can be disabled in production as well ?

Comment: If you want security you have to do host name checking. Otherwise, you're left wide open to a man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do?